# Avoid dropdown selection change event during view load

Tags: wpf

Grid contains dropdown control. I want to avoid selection change event during view load. What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you upload your code, or what you have so far? Or even a picture. It helps out when trying to answer.

Comment: private void Comment_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {  gridEntityTransaction.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Comments", string.Empty);}........                                                                                We have binded grid in User control load event.During user control load this code in selection changed event should not get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know what `dropdown` control is in WPF

I have tried with `combobox` and **SelectionChanged** event in not firing at form load

Here's my code

```
<Window x:Class="Q6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Q6"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                  Height="30" Width="100">
            <ComboBoxItem>Alpha</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Beta</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Gamma</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code-behind :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Q6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
             //Not firing at load time
        }
    }
}
```